# Using scrollview to adjust to content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to adjust the size of the scrollview dependent on the amount of content that's in the subview (highlighted as SubView Content in the hierarchy). This is a picture of hierarchy, storyboard, and simulator.

[image: Imgur]

My scrollview has constraints of 0 to all four sides and I have a "content view" inside the scroll view that contains all of the contents. This content view is constrained to the scrollview. The content view has equal widths to the view. The height of the content view will be determined by the contents inside.

First question: Does the scroll view need to get its height from the content view, which the content view gets its height from the contents within?

Second question: How do I achieve this in code and storyboard? The white box (highlighted as SubView Content in the hierarchy) will have different amounts of content inside. I need the height of this box to change dynamically, which will change the size the content view (and scroll view as well).

Below is some code to start:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var myContentView: UIView! //this is the content container

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    let scrollViewBounds = myContentView.bounds
    let containerViewBounds = ?
```

Where do I go from here?